# NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getOrDefault(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Ljava/util/Map;

Tags: android, kotlin, android-databinding, android-livedata

I've got the crash on Meizu device with Android 5.0. This crash doesn't appear on most of the devices.

The error is: `java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No interface method getOrDefault(Ljava/lang/Object;Ljava/lang/Object;)Ljava/lang/Object; in class Ljava/util/Map; or its super classes (declaration of 'java.util.Map' appears in /system/framework/core-libart.jar)`

[image]

Did someone experience something similar?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The **`getOrDefault`** method was added in API level 24 and runtimes below API level 24 don't have that method. Thats why it's not working in Android API level 21.

official [link](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/util/Map#getOrDefault(java.lang.Object,%20V))

Comment: Is there any way to generate warning or any lint rule to detect usage of such methods at compile time?

Comment: so what to do? any suggestions here?

Comment: yes same issue is coming for can you pleas help me for this solution

Answer (score 1):

Especially this function you can do this:

```java
//ask your app running more modern API as level 24 (Build.VERSION_CODES.N(ougat))
result = (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) ?          
    map.getOrDefault(value, default) :
    // if not, then need to solve with similar code of original code in next below
    ((map.get(value) != null) ? map.get(value) : default);
```

There is a source code in the original one
c:\Users\Your_username\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\sources\android-29\java\util\Map.java:

```
    ...
    default V getOrDefault(Object key, V defaultValue) {
        V v;
        return (((v = get(key)) != null) || containsKey(key))
            ? v
            : defaultValue;
    }
    ...
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `getOrElse` instead. It accepts 2nd parameter as lambda. So,an example is:

```
dataItems.getOrElse(id) { null }
```